# Join threads from thread pool

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have 30+ tasks that can be executed in parallel.
I use ThreadPool for each task.
But parent-function should not return until all tasks has completed.

I need a thread sync handle that would release WaitOne when its count reaches 0.
Something like:

```
foo.StartWith(myTasks.Count);
foreach (var task in myTasks) {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => { task(state); foo.Release(); });
}
foo.WaitOne();
```

`Semaphore` feels right, just can't figure out how to apply it here.

Comment: Not putting this as an answer, as it goes on a tangent from your question, but if you started these tasks with BeginInvoke instead of as threadpool items, you could get the WaitHandles from the AysncResults, and call WaitAll on them. If the advantages of threadpool outweigh this, then this isn't much of an answer, but if it doesn't, then it's worth looking at.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
int running = myTasks.Count;
AutoResetEvent done = new AutoResetEvent(false);
foreach (var task in myTasks) {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => { 
    task(state); 
    if (0 == Interlocked.Decrement(ref running))
      done.Set ();
    });
}
done.WaitOne();
```

With C# 4.0 you can use the new [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997365.aspx) primitive.

Comment: Or the 4.0 Task class, better mousetrap.

Answer (score 0):

[Joe Duffy](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com) wrote a great article on this sort of thing:

[CLR Inside Out: 9 Reusable Parallel Data Structures and Algorithms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163427.aspx#S1)

I'm eyballing the CountdownLatch as particularly appropriate for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

According to this article: [Overview of Synchronization Primitives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228964.aspx)

C# has a built-in type for this scenario, CountDownEvent: [CountdownEvent Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx)

Or a similiar one: [Barrier (.NET Framework)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997287.aspx)

For newer versions, use the TPL (Task Parallel Library) , and for this scenerio this code is relevant:

```
// Create an ActionBlock<int> object that prints its input
// and throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException if the input
// is less than zero.
var throwIfNegative = new ActionBlock<int>(n =>
{
   Console.WriteLine("n = {0}", n);
   if (n < 0)
   {
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
   }
});

// Post values to the block.
throwIfNegative.Post(0);
throwIfNegative.Post(-1);
throwIfNegative.Post(1);
throwIfNegative.Post(-2);
throwIfNegative.Complete();

// Wait for completion in a try/catch block.
try
{
   throwIfNegative.Completion.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
   // If an unhandled exception occurs during dataflow processing, all
   // exceptions are propagated through an AggregateException object.
   ae.Handle(e =>
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Encountered {0}: {1}", 
         e.GetType().Name, e.Message);
      return true;
   });
}

/* Output:
n = 0
n = -1
Encountered ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range
 of valid values.
*/
```

from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx